# Unrecognized command!

Tags: graphics, captions

I'm writing my thesis with latex, i created a main file and i included in this a `package.sty`, the index,the sections and so on. I encountered some problems in using the `sidecap` or `floatrow` packages. I wrote in my sty file `\usepackage{sidecap}` but when i call the function `\begin{SCfigure}` latex says that the command is unrecognized. The same happens with the `floatrow` package. It's not essential that i use side captions in my work document but from my point of view the use of them gives a better style and format. If some one can solve my doubt I will be very grateful.

**EDIT - posted Code from Comment below **

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openany,reqno,table]{art‌​icle} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{sidecap} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{SCfigure} 
\centering 
\caption{frame XY} 
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{frame} 
\end{SCfigure} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! We cannot say anything about the source of the problem without seeing the actual code that produces the error. Please make a copy of your document and strip it down as much as possible while still showing the error. Then post the code by adding it to your question (just use the edit button left below your post).

Comment: Are these packages installed?

Comment: Please also use TeX-related terminology a bit more carefully. E.g., `SCfigure` is an 'environment', not a 'function'. Do tell us which document class you use, which packages you load (via `\usepackage` statements) in the preamble, and which instruction(s) give rise to error and/or warning messages. Do also share the precise contents of the warning and/or error messages.

Comment: I do't have errors but doesn't work. Now i will try to explain. I write the code the pdf is processed without problems. When i view the file my figure is at left or right of the page as should be but my caption is not at the side of the figure, or better is at his side but doesn't starts from the top. Is as latex makes the caption on the respective side but afer the figure. Hence when i view my code the command \begin{SCfigure} is highlighted in orange and if i go on it latex gives a small messagge: unrecognized command.

Comment: Let me know if ever see something like this in you code

Comment: Sorry but it is impossible to guess what you have done and what output you got. Make a small complete example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that uses SCfigure but does not work as you expect. Then people can debug it.

Comment: how can you say "I do(n)'t have errors" but then go on to say you get an unrecognised command error?

Comment: Is it your editor that says "unrecognised command" or do you get this from tex?

Comment: it's not the editor i got it from tex, in the final document seems to work but not as i exepect, even if i write the same code that is one the manual.. i cannot write you all the code. In a main file i wrote a \documentclass...{book}. i included in it the package.sty,the idex,sections and all the subparts of the document.. So is impossible that some one can debug it there are pages and pages of code. However really is not a problem i will try one time more, if doesn't work i will use the normal \begin{figure} with the caption. Probably i'm doing some mistake in setting the options of the pack.

Comment: Your original document isn't what you should post. You should be able to construct a document which just shows the issue that you are seeing with sccaption. Otherwise it is impossible to guess what this question is about.

Comment: ok this is a simple code that i wrote to make an example.. but i don't know how to show you the result.

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openany,reqno,table]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\begin{document}
\begin{SCfigure}
\centering
\caption{frame XY}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{frame}
\end{SCfigure}
\end{document}

Comment: The caption is not at the leftside of the figure, but is after the figure in the left corner. I need it alligned with the figure doesn't matter if is at the top or bottom. What is m mistake?

Comment: No, make an edit and add it to your question!

Comment: Also to the experienced users, it would have been helpful if you've put the correct Welcome  messages…

Comment: So: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Welcome to Latex.Please read the Welcome page where you can find all the information for the first steps here.

Answer (score 1):

(Not a real answer, just a placeholder to narrow down the problem.)

Haven't yet been able to reproduce your symptom. Please verify my result from the following document, and then we can go from there to see where your problem really lies.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{sidecap} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{SCfigure} 
\centering 
\caption{frame XY}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{frame}
\end{SCfigure} 
\end{document}
```

[image]